# how to convert whole jsp page to pdf file in java?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, itext

I am having some contents on my jsp page like some text and tables now i want to save the whole page in pdf format can anyone tel me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

IText is another popular library that we had used in the past to generate PDFs using Java. You can read about it at [iText PDF Library](http://itextpdf.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) to generate PDF documents

Comment: can u please suggest me something about Apache PDFBox?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the exact same HTML output in PDF format, you can install a driver and "print" the page through a PDF FILE PRINTER.

If you need to generate PDFs from your java application server, I would recommend using a library or a reporting system to help. Like [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports).